# How to exclude last item in v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to **JavaScript** and JS frameworks. I have the following snippet of **Vuejs** code:

```
    <div v-for="coefficient in coefficients" class="coefficient">
        <div>
            <span class="name">name:{{coefficient.name}}</span>
            <span class="value">value:{{coefficient.value}}</span>
            <span>---</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the output:

```
name: Ubuntu
value: 1
---
name: MacOS
value: 2
---
name: Windows
value: 3
---
```

How can I exclude the last item of `coefficients` by Vuejs?

Comment: You're supposed to create the smaller array in your controller code, then iterate over that in your html template. `v-for` doesn't support slicing, afaik.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a computed property, or you could use `coefficients.slice(0, -1)` like so:

```js
new Vue({
  data : {
    coefficients : [
    {name : "a", value : 2}, 
    {name : "b", value : 3}, 
    {name : "c", value : 4}]
  },
  el : "#app"  
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="coefficient in coefficients.slice(0, -1)" class="coefficient">
        <div>
            <span class="name">name:{{coefficient.name}}</span>
            <span class="value">value:{{coefficient.value}}</span>
            <span>---</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

just use `v-for="coefficient in coefficients.slice(0,-1)"`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/4315/)